# Which SQLite database to be downloaded for Xamarin.Forms

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, sqlite-net

I would like to save data from the register screen into database in my xamarin.Forms app, I am planning to use `SQLite` database.
I have already downloaded and installed the `SQLite.Net.Core-PCL 3.1.1` library in my project.

Which database should be selected from the following link
https://www.sqlite.org/download.html:
Should I use `Precompiled Binaries for Android`
or 
`Precompiled Binaries for Windows` ?

Environment details

```
OS: Windows 10 Enterprise, 64 bit operating system
IDE: Visual Studio 19 preview
Xamarin.Forms
SQLite.Net.Core-PCL 3.1.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/ as it is the orginal and *updated* version.

It contains a reference to the  `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` package which in turn provides the platform dependent SQLite native libraries for all the various platforms and frameworks:

- .NETCoreApp 0.0
- .NETFramework 3.5
- .NETFramework 4.0
- .NETFramework 4.5
- .NETStandard 1.1
- MonoAndroid 0.0
- Portable Class Library (.NETFramework 4.5, Windows 8.0, WindowsPhoneApp 8.1)
- UAP 10.0
- Windows 8.0
- Windows 8.1
- WindowsPhone 8.0
- WindowsPhoneApp 8.1
- Xamarin.iOS 1.0
- Xamarin.Mac 2.0

re: https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

re: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green/

Comment: Which database should I need to  download and use ?

Comment: Is this a database ? >> `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green`

Comment: @soccerway You do not have to, that package already has them pre-compiled|pre-included.

Comment: @soccerway Remove the sqlite package that you added and add `sqlite-net-pcl` and it will handle all the SQLite dependancies for you. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/databases

Comment: How to remove the `SQLite.Net.Core-PCL 3.1.1` from the project ?

Comment: Successfully uninstalled and installed the `sqlite-net-pcl` as you advised. Now how can I open the database and add relevant table ?

Comment: @soccerway You do it via code within your app: https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net#synchronous-api Also read the link in my comment above.